# Confusing audit case: "not an answer" was already fixed into a comment

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing the "First Post" queue, I was presented with a case where my first thoughts were ["this is not an answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14886474).

However, following the queue link, I noticed that there was no answer. Instead, all I saw was [a comment with the same contents of the supposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402330/how-to-prevent-facebook-in-app-browser-from-opening-my-website-links/41395365#comment69992769_36402330).

At first, I was confused—"Why am I reviewing a comment?" Then I suspected it was probably an audit. This was already dealt with; the answer was flagged, deleted, and moved into a comment.

But how should I respond?

1. Since the issue had already been taken care of, there was no action needed. So that should be the answer. There's no need to flag a problem if there is no problem;
2. On the other hand, since this is probably an audit, I should select the option that was appropriate when the answer was made. So I shold flag it. But isn't this cheating?

I found this a bit confusing, but decided to go with #1. And failed the audit.

IMO this audit is bad because:

1. It favors reviewers who don't inspect the link; and
2. It favors reviewers who realize this is an audit.

Maybe this should be removed from the audit list?

Comment: Note that when you flag an audit, your flag doesn't actually get created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You failed the audit because you're thinking too far.

Audits are supposed to catch reviewers that are blindly clicking on buttons.

You should handle each review case as if it was a real post. If you can recognize an audit, you basically have already passed it, unless you're not doing what I said the sentence before.

BTW, mods can convert answers to comments, which is usually done for "answers" that provide some relevant info but don't answer the question itself.

Answer (score 6):

Yay, you are paying attention! You passed the audit by that notion alone.

Audits are there to catch people that are doing nothing but wait for the 'No action' button to become active, and so then click their way to a badge. You are not one of those people.

Just skip this one. It's fine, you don't *have* to make a decision on this one. After all, you already figured out is was handled. But if you are going to actually 'handle the post' then handle the post as presented in the review screen. An audit tests if you would pick the 'right' option for the post *as it was at the time when it was problematic*. You are expected to handle a post with the review screen information alone.